# Converting from Windows-1255 to UTF-8 in Node JS

Tags: node.js, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-1255

I'm extracting text from a Windows-1255-encoded webpage using Node.js. I'm trying to decode the text using the [windows-1255](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-1255).

After installing it using NPM and requiring it in the relevant file, I tried using it like this:

```
var title = windows1255.decode('#title').text());
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Morgan

Answer (score 1):

don't know if you still waiting for an answer about this issue, but the following worked for me...

When fetching the data (a file), I set the get options of encoding to be binary:

```
var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'myURL',
        encoding: 'binary' 
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {

        //deal with hebrew encoding
        csvString = encoding.convert(body, 'UTF8', "CP1255").toString();
```

Then for I switch encoding from `CP1255` (=`windows1255`) to `UTF8`.

Hope it helps :)